# jQuery changing scroll results in event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

i know there are a few similar questions regards how to handle events when scroll hit bottom or top but none answers here helped me so far. 
I want event to trigger when user scroll to bottom and top (load some content, not important here). The thing is if user scroll to bottom i move scroll a little bit up. I do this so that user can get new content by just scrolling down again, otherwise he would need to go up and down so that he can load new content. Similar thing when he reach top happen. Thing is when i use scrollTop() to move scroll up then scroll event happen twice (in other word, script execute event when page is on bottom twice). I cant use unbind suggested in some other questions here as then after user hit bottom once, he would not be able to do it again. setTimeout also did not help.

This is current code:

```
$("#scroller").on('scroll', function (e) {
   clearTimeout(_throttleTimer);
   _throttleTimer = setTimeout(function () {
      if($("#scroller").scrollTop() + $("#scroller").innerHeight() >= $("#scroller")[0].scrollHeight)  {
         alert("bottom");
         $("#scroller").scrollTop($("#scroller").scrollTop()-10); //move scroll up a bit
         }else if($("#scroller").scrollTop() == 0)
         {
            alert("top");
            $("#scroller").scrollTop(10); //move scroll down a bit
         }
    }, _throttleDelay);
});
```

You can see example here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0kpu42t/2/). How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this condition to [Determine if an element has been totally scrolled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight#Determine_if_an_element_has_been_totally_scrolled):

```
element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0kpu42t/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement was wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/q0kpu42t/5/

You dont need a timer or something

```
var $document = $(document);
$document.ready(function () {

$("#scroller").on('scroll', function () {

       if(this.scrollHeight - this.scrollTop === this.clientHeight)  {
            alert("bottom");

            $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()-10);

        }else if($(this).scrollTop() == 0)
            {
              alert("top");

              $("#scroller").scrollTop(10);
            }

    });
});
console.log($("#scroller")[0].clientHeight);
console.log($("#scroller").innerHeight());
$("#scroller")[0].scrollTop=10;
```

Comment: yes,this seems to work. But timeout is still nice in some cases,as when you drag and release scroll handle it still can be triggered multiple times. Timeout seems to help there. While using mouse scroll this problem doesnt exist.Thx though.